# Maven parallel build failed because package used in tests not exist

Tags: java, maven

My project could be built successfully with the command: `mvn clean install`. But I am trying to use `mvn clean install -T 1C`, it gives a batch of errors like `package org.junit not exist` or `cannot find symbol XXX` because of the classes import from other modules (e.g. common). I checked the entire error message, all of them are happens for classes in the test folder.

The project has multiple modules. e.g.

```
- common
- module1
- modele2
```

In the root `pom.xml`

```
...
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            ...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>common-module-group-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>common-artifact-id</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>common-module-group-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>common-artifact-id</artifactId>
                <type>test-jar</type>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>module1-group-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>module1-artifact-id</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>module1-group-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>module1-artifact-id</artifactId>
                <type>test-jar</type>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>module2-group-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>module2-artifact-id</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>module2-group-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>module2-artifact-id</artifactId>
                <type>test-jar</type>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        ...
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*TestU.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                            <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
                            <version>2.22.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                ...
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.4</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

And the common module has `pom.xml`

```
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

junit dependences are not included. I also tried include them, still got same errors.

The `pom.xml` for module1 and module2 are like

```
...
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>common-module-group-id</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-artifact-id</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

The errors are only happens when I am trying build `module1` and `module2` together with `-T 1C` option.

Comment: A `test-jar` needs to be defined as dependency by two things first `<type>test-jar</type>` as you already did but you missed to add also `<classifier>tests</classifier>` See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html Another question is coming to my mind: Why don't you follow default naming schemas for unit tests which means `*Test.java`  instead of self defined naming schemas? Apart from that if you need test-jars this usually means you have an architectural issue in your project...Most of the time it's better making a separate module ....

Comment: and extract the code into that but put the code into `src/main/java` and write tests for that code as well and use it as a usual dependency but with scope test...

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you for pointing out the `test-jar` staff. Add `<classifier>` do not solve the problem. And I also tried to remove the dependency of those test jars, still got the same errors.

Comment: Than you have general problem with your dependencies in your build. Testcase. Cleanup your local cache I really mean delete it and afterwards start your project fro m root via `mvn clean package`  which must be working if it's not working you have dependency issues in your build which I expect...You can also use `mvn clean package -Dmaven.repo.local=AnotherDirectoryWithAbsolutePath`...so you don't need to delete your local repository ...